# Better Algorithm for 'Sweet Candies'

Tags: algorithms

Problem: [image]

Short Summary:

Given a list of numbers $a_k$ and $r_1, r_2, c_1, c_2$,
calculate

> $\sum_{x=r_1}^{r_2} \sum_{y=c_1}^{c_2} a_{(x + y) mod N }$

Although this is a computer programming problem, I believe there is math involved in the question to simplify it. When I make a 'brute-force' solution, it run too slow.

Suppose $N = 3 \times 10^5, r_1 = c_1 = 0$ and $ r_2 = c_2 = N$
With straight-forward brute force I would need to do near $10^11$ Calculations vs around 10^8 Calculations per second.

Is there a better algorithm/way to simplify the calculation?

Thanks.

(P.S. If this should be transferred to StackOverflow, I would remove this.)

Comment: First I would try to reduce your formula into $\sum_{k=r_1+c_1}^{r_2+c_2}f(k)a_{k \pmod N}$, where $f(k)$ is the number of solutions of $r_1 \leq x \leq r_2$, $c_1 \leq y \leq c_2$, $x + y = k$. So $f(k) = \min\{r_2 - r_1 + 1, c_2 - c_1 + 1, r_2+c_2-k+1, k-r_1-c_1+1\}$.

Comment: Sorry, but it is still not efficient enough. Is there anything I'm missing here? Code: https://pastebin.com/qNnYw4m0 in Python.

Comment: How much time do you need to cut down? I am not familiar with Python, but I am wondering if it is possible to save some marginal time by cutting down repetitive operations in the loops, and avoid the modular operations... etc. But I do not have any idea how to improve this mathematically at the moment.

Comment: I believe some clever math is the way. Once I have any clue/solution I will share it here, thx.